# Unable to use a selector of a sub-component in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components

I want to "insert" task.component's view into my main app.component.html (root template) as follows:

(app.module.ts)

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TaskComponent } from './task/task.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TaskComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

(app.component.ts)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'planner';
}
```

(task.component.ts)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-task',
  templateUrl: './task.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./task.component.css']
})

export class TaskComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("Task comonent initialized!");
  }

}
```

(app.component.html)

```html
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<app-task></app-task>
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title + 1 }}!
  </h1>
  <img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNTAgMjUwIj4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNERDAwMzEiIGQ9Ik0xMjUgMzBMMzEuOSA2My4ybDE0LjIgMTIzLjFMMTI1IDIzMGw3OC45LTQzLjcgMTQuMi0xMjMuMXoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjQzMwMDJGIiBkPSJNMTI1IDMwdjIyLjItLjFWMjMwbDc4LjktNDMuNyAxNC4yLTEyMy4xTDEyNSAzMHoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCAgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRkZGRiIgZD0iTTEyNSA1Mi4xTDY2LjggMTgyLjZoMjEuN2wxMS43LTI5LjJoNDkuNGwxMS43IDI5LjJIMTgzTDEyNSA1Mi4xem0xNyA4My4zaC0zNGwxNy00MC45IDE3IDQwLjl6IiAvPgogIDwvc3ZnPg==">
</div>
<h2>Here are some links to help you start: </h2>
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/tutorial">Tour of Heroes</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki">CLI Documentation</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://blog.angular.io/">Angular blog</a></h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So despite the fact that I have linked the task.component to the module I do not have access to its selector. Did I forget some import/export statements. Is that in fact a misunderstanding of angular's architecture/principle of structure?
The file `task.component.html` only consists of 
`<p>
  task works!
</p>`

Edit:

I also received the following error from the client's console:
[[image: error screenshot]]

Comment: well, u need to import the component.
how do u expect to use it if ur not importing it into the component u want to work with?

Comment: But I added the component in the root module? What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact restarting the server with `ng serve` did not solve the problem and therefore was not responsible for the missing interpolation of the component's template.

Rebuilding the app was the only (and ugliest) option for me which caused additionally work of course.

1. Delete all files of your project (all files in the layer in which amongst others `node_modules` is placed)
2. Setting up the project with `ng new (...)`
3. Building clean components with terminal commands (`ng g c (...)` / `ng generate component (...)`)

Answer (score 1):

To add a New Component to the Module that you're working on (which in your case is the AppModule), you first create a component(just use AngularCLI to do this by running the command `ng g c task`), and Angular CLI automatically adds it to your `AppModule`'s `declarations` array. Then you can simply add the selector tag to your app.component.html to load that up

Just add `<app-task></app-task>` to your app.component.html

#### UPDATE

In some cases, even when you do everything properly, Angular doesn't recognise the Component that was added recently. **Try breaking your local service** by `Ctrl + C` on Windows or `Cmd + C` on Mac. **And then run `ng serve` to serve up the App again.** This generally happens when a Component is Added while the Server is running.

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7jfst5) for your ref just to cross check if you missed something.

Comment: Sorry, I did not included this line to the question (With that, it doesnt work too).

Comment: Do you have any html markup in your TaskComponent HTML?

Comment: Try breaking the local service. And running it again using `ng serve`

Comment: Did you try breaking the Served App and running it again using `ng serve`? Try clearing the cache as well.

Comment: Yes I did @see answer.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly shows in the place of the selector `<app-task></app-task>` that you added in `app.component.html` ?? What error in the console. This selector should work and be rendered to `TaskComponent` html view !!!!

Comment: Angular outputs a blank page and the error which can be seen in the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what did you mean for linking components?

Following the structure that you shared it's working if you want see something, you must create the task-component.html because doesn't exist.

And the idea a component is that each component must has its logical indipendent to work.

And ways to share resources is using EventEmitters or binding properties.

This is the sceenshot that I saw and I can see the component created.

[image: Screenshoot]

Answer (score -1):

Try re-running ng serve after stopping it. Hope you added component using Angular-Cli command - 
`ng generate component task`

Comment: Yes I did. I also used --model app.model.ts